# Azure Kubernetes Services scale up trigger

Tags: azure, kubernetes, autoscaling

I am trying to figure out what is the trigger to scale AKS cluster out horizontally with nodes. I am having a cluster that runs on 103% CPU for 5+ minutes but there is no action taken. Any ideas what the triggers are and how I could customize them? If I start more jobs the cluster will lower the CPU allocation for all pods.

The article that MS has doesn't have anything specific around that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler

Comment: How exactly are you checking your nodes' CPU utilization?

Answer (score 0):

You need to notice that:

> The cluster autoscaler is a Kubernetes component. Although the AKS
> cluster uses a virtual machine scale set for the nodes, don't manually
> enable or edit settings for scale set autoscale in the Azure portal or
> using the Azure CLI. Let the Kubernetes cluster autoscaler manage the
> required scale settings.

Which brings us to the actual [Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler#cluster-autoscaler):

> Cluster Autoscaler is a tool that automatically adjusts the size of
> the Kubernetes cluster when one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - **there are pods that failed to run in the cluster due to insufficient resources.**
> - there are nodes in the cluster that have been underutilized for an extended period of time and their pods can be placed on other existing
>   nodes.

The first condition above is the trigger you are looking for.

To get more details regarding the installation and configuration you can go through the [Cluster Autoscaler on Azure](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/README.md#cluster-autoscaler-on-azure). For example, you can customize your CA based on the [Resources](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/README.md#resources):

> When scaling from an empty VM Scale Set (0 instances), Cluster
> Autoscaler will evaluate the provided presources (cpu, memory,
> ephemeral-storage) based on that VM Scale Set's backing instance type.
> This can be overridden (for instance, to account for system reserved
> resources) by specifying capacities with VMSS tags, formated as:
> `k8s.io_cluster-autoscaler_node-template_resources_<resource name>: <resource value>`. For instance:
>
> ```
> k8s.io_cluster-autoscaler_node-template_resources_cpu: 3800m
> k8s.io_cluster-autoscaler_node-template_resources_memory: 11Gi
> ```